# gulp-eslint Environment key "es2021" is unknown

Tags: gulp, eslint

I have a project with the following dependencies;

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-htmllint": "0.0.19",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
    "gulp-jsmin": "^0.1.5"
```

When I try to run a gulp task that lints javascript, using eslint/gulp-eslint;

```
function javascript() {
    return src('private/script/**')
        //.pipe(jsmin())
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())
        .pipe(dest('public/script'));
}
```

I get the following error;

```
Error: .eslintrc.json » eslint-config-standard:
        Environment key "es2021" is unknown
```

I used `npx eslint --init` to generate the following configuration file;

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "standard"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018
    },
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

i have done an npm install, to make sure I have the latest version of the dependencies. I have also read on guthub that the error might have something to do with `gulp-eslint` as it is an old version and might not be using the current version of `eslint`, however, in I have changed `gulp-eslint` package.json to use the latest version of `eslint` and no luck. I also updated node/npm to their latest lts versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting the `eslint` folder in the `node_modules` folder for `gulp-eslint`. this forces node to use the version you have as a dependency rather than the version the project maintainer wants to use.

[it appears this is a known issue.](https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint/pull/255)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that gulp-eslint works with ESLint 6 under the hub, and ESLint 6 does not support the `es2021` environment (see the [supported environments of ESLint 6](https://eslint.org/docs/6.0.0/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)).

I'm going to show three options to handle this. The best solution will depend on your setup and requirements.

### Method 1: Replace `es2021` with an equivalent definition

The `es2021` environment is the same as `es2020` with the addition of the globals `AggregateError`, `FinalizationRegistry` and `WeakRef` (see the [definition of `es2021`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/32ac37a76b2e009a8f106229bc7732671d358189/conf/globals.js#L116-L121)), so you could enter these settings in your .eslintrc configuration file instead to obtain the same result.

```json
{
  ...
  "env": {
    ...
    "es2020": true
  },
  ...
  "globals": {
    ...
    "AggregateError": "readonly",
    "FinalizationRegistry": "readonly",
    "WeakRef": "readonly"
  },
  ...
}
```

### Method 2: Force gulp-eslint to use ESLint 7

If you are using npm >= 8.3 < 9.0 (check this with `npm -v`), you can override the version of ESLint used by gulp-eslint.

To do so, first add an override entry to your package.json file like this:

```json
{
  ...
  "overrides": {
    "gulp-eslint": {
      "eslint": "7"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

then run:

```
npm install
```

Now, gulp-eslint will work with the latest version of ESLint 7 which does recognize the `es2021` environment (it exists in ESLint >= 7.8).

Note that gulp-eslint does still not support ESLint 7, so some things may not work as expected. Particularly, some plugins may fail to load or produce runtime errors.

### Method 3: Use gulp-eslint-new

[gulp-eslint-new](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-eslint-new) works with ESLint 8 and can be used in most situations as a drop-in replacement for gulp-eslint, provided that the configuration is compatible with both versions.

- Uninstall gulp-eslint with

  ```bash
  npm uninstall gulp-eslint
  ```
- Install gulp-eslint-new with

  ```bash
  npm install -D gulp-eslint-new
  ```
- In your gulpfile, replace the import of `gulp-eslint` with `gulp-eslint-new`.

**DISCLAIMER**: I am currently the only maintainer of `gulp-eslint-new`.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by upgrading eslint version to version 7
This is what [image]my package json looks like

Comment: Random: Nice Webstorm theme. care to share?

Comment: that was material ui themen @LuisRodriguez